# Paperjs boolean union and substraction (unite and subtract)

Tags: boolean-operations, paperjs, subtraction

Trying to understand how does unite and subtract methodes works in paperjs (paper.js).

```
var postyle = { fillColor:'grey', strokeColor: 'black'}

var p1 = Path.Circle({
        center: new Point(80, 50),
        radius: 50
    })
var p2 = Path.Circle({
        center: new Point(200, 50),
        radius: 50
    })

var p3 = Path.Circle({
        center: new Point(120, 60),
        radius: 50
    })
var p4 = Path.Circle({
        center: new Point(190, 60),
        radius: 15
    })
var p5 = Path.Circle({
        center: new Point(50, 60),
        radius: 10
    })
var p6 = Path.Circle({
        center: new Point(80, 40),
        radius: 10
    })

var pos=p1.unite(p2)
var neg=p3.unite(p4)

var boolp=pos.subtract(neg)

var path = boolp//.unite(p5)//.unite(p6)

path.style=postyle
```

You can try it in http://sketch.paperjs.org

It works like this, but if you uncomment the `.unite(p5)`, the p5 circle is not union'ed with the others (the circle in the left quarter of moon).

If you uncomment also the `.unite(p6)`, the p5 is now subtract'ed instead of union'ed. p6 is well union'ed.

If you change p6 to `Point(60,40)`, p5 is well union'ed and p6 has the problem of union'ing.

What goes wrong ?

Thx

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is a lot going on. Maybe you could simplify your example a bit more and use colors to illustrate the problem better? http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/lZLLboMwEEV/xfImIKHwCEYtEav8QKRu2RgYJQhqW8a0iyj/3jGhIk0VObAyd+7cM35cqOCfQHP60YGpzzSgtWzsfym+uCYqJgU5cnPeHlpd9+BdSkHmrwZhQOdEwDc5ylYY7y0KCIv8YPFo3rTjkKN6067+vhQq3g5Gyw4OspcaAZuq53W3wdJMTdZQk+hFbOLC7tZg4wSx2QvYnQubrsK+P8XG7B6burBsDZY9p/7ZLHNRs7UPKnVT7QLZmYsthwLf3ihaA55KbKeVBZwKvKRZTv3Jj97HtJMGEDYNGx5rGpqFU0nZq2JKGCujeW08bLnlTrX/c45wNyaeDqqTcx+Gv4Mxf1lnNiwMrfMxS41a9ZhGrz8=

Comment: The problem appears only in some configuration. Simpler config does not show the problem.     With setting colors before boolean operations, it seems not to work. `var p1 = Path.Circle({
        center: new Point(80, 50),
        radius: 50
    })
p1.style={ fillColor:'blue', strokeColor: 'black'}

var p2 = Path.Circle({
        center: new Point(120, 50),
        radius: 50
    })
p2.style={ fillColor:'green', strokeColor: 'black'}

var path=p1.unite(p2)
//path.style={ fillColor:'grey', strokeColor: 'black'}`   Uncomment last line to make it works.

Comment: This then really seems like a problem with paper.js itself. So it would be better that you create an [issue](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/new) on their [github page](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js).

Answer (score 0):

This question is explaining its answer itself.
As Union of the path with smaller path being whole immersed in the parent path will result the parent path itself.
If you change the x positions of the smaller circles you are getting the union correct as it should be, refer [sketch.paper.js](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/nZTBjoIwEIZfpeECJgYFgd0l4eQLmOxx3UPBWSXUlpSiMcZ332kRA2hIkIRD/5n5/w8KvVqcHsGKre8CVHaw5lYmdnp9opKUolIXBiQhV/KXM7YWTMjY3ku42HNSKSkKaDRip4xmhX3byi3Xtxn3cHJD1cFd5zJj4Fx1hdyvDLgCnORwJhuRc+V8LuckXM7m3S5Jd3ldxaj35H62hJ3dVm+zR7w/Ld5fvpufshoGAA+I1TQIz0eI6D0IvQEvXkMwkeBrhMALRwjwuwD+iiCcRvAxBjD2CrILfZkfTcuPMD94Jz+V4jwEeECIKik9t+a5Aqf0TQ01t+OAlM2/ZWq+K+EoTuA0rV5vqR057JNy1ToGRkdt6FjmvPkssLfnGPSWrWsqBCsTQ1anStJMOWhqWkxpaN/+e3qi66dJhsQl7gHOND537rBj/dR/oAr79VjbHpniYmG0bj9K4VCInp4QRfR0zbGW3I83PPNSCbQo9eZXVvzze/sH)